# Doxygen: How to redefine void

Tags: c, doxygen

I use a library which redefine the void type (among others):

```
#define XX_VOID void
```

So when I run doxygen on a code like

```
/**
 * @brief Function description
 */
XX_VOID foo(XX_VOID)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

I get the warning

```
file.c:10: warning: return type of member foo is not documented
```

How can I tell Doxygen that `XX_VOID` is void so there is no return value ?

Comment: I don't want to add something like `@return none` to all the functions using this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the [`MACRO_EXPANSION`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_expand_only_predef) tag:

> **MACRO_EXPANSION**
>
> If the `MACRO_EXPANSION` tag is set to `YES`, doxygen will expand all macro names in the source code. If set to `NO`, only conditional compilation will be performed. Macro expansion can be done in a controlled way by setting [`EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_expand_only_predef) to `YES`.
>
> The default value is: `NO`.
>
> This tag requires that the tag [`ENABLE_PREPROCESSING`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enable_preprocessing) is set to `YES`.

With `MACRO_EXPANSION` set to `YES` the result after doxygen preprocessing becomes:

```
void foo(void)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it expand the macro in the parameter list, too?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I tried the `PREDEFINED` and `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` tags but I missed the `MACRO_EXPANSION`.

Comment: @unwind You're right. Fixed in the answer. Thank you!